# Почему не работает выпадающий календарь в форме регистрации Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, плагин

Добрый день! Сайт на Joomla 3. Есть форма регистрации на сайте http://alcopribor.ru/login/registration

Там есть поле "Дата рождения" и иконка календарика. По идее при клике по ней должен выпасть dropdown datepicker - однако, ничего не происходит. Реализовано это штатным плагином Джумлы "Пользователь - Профиль", путь к нему \plugins\user\profile. За календарь отвечает внутренний файл плагина fields\dob.php (сокращение от "date-of-birth"), содержащий class JFormFieldDob extends JFormFieldCalendar.

Что необходимо сделать чтобы работал выпадающий календарик при клике по иконке? Насколько я знаю, JFormFieldCalendar реализует его же - почему в моём случае может не работать?

Answer (score 1):

Решение: проблема возникала от того, что подключение скриптов календаря

```
<script src="/media/system/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/calendar-setup.js"></script>
```

...находилось по положению в коде страницы намного ниже, чем обращение к Calendar.setup()! (Прямо перед  была эта вставка). Естественно, возникала Reference error: Calendar is not defined!

Задача была решена после того, как в настройках T3-темы я добавил код подключения скриптов непосредственно в самое начало блока . Кроме того, не менее важным было отключить дублирующее добавление этих же скриптов в конце перед  (т.е. которое было исходно) - если это не делать, работать не будет. Отключение производится добавлением в index.php темы следующего PHP-кода:

```
unset(
$this->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/system/js/calendar.js'],
$this->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/system/js/calendar-setup.js']
);
```